# Check if Internet access is available on Android

Tags: android

How can i check that internet has or not. But i found this code but when wifi connected it return true, but i know that there is not internet. No internet access.

```
 public boolean chechInternet_con(){
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    // Here if condition check for wifi and mobile network is available or not.
    // If anyone of them is available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;

    if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Have you tested your code in device?

Comment: This has been answered please check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096987/check-real-internet-connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public boolean isInternetOn(Context ctx) {
        this.mContext = ctx;
        ConnectivityManager Connect_Manager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        State connected = NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
        State connecting = NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING;
        State disconnected = NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED;

        State info0 = Connect_Manager.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
        State info1 = Connect_Manager.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();

        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
        if (info0 == connected || info0 == connecting || info1 == connecting
                || info1 == connected) {

            Log.d("Internet", "Connected");
            return true;
        } else if (info0 == disconnected || info1 == disconnected) {
            Log.d("Internet", "DisConnected");
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you remove this  info0 == connecting || info1 == connecting condition from the "if" and then check?

Comment: my device connected to wifi but no internet access, i can not enter sites:(

Answer (score 0):

See below code

```
    public static boolean checkConnection(Context context) {

    final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final NetworkInfo netInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank But you only are checking connected or connecting but my device connected to wifi but no internet access. i mean i can not enter any sites:(

Answer (score 0):

So, its connected to wi-fi network but no internet access. Right?

Try to ping 8.8.8.8 or google.com to know whether there is internet access.
 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android) will help you.