# Android webview page unavailable

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I developed a small android webview app to access an internal (local network) PHP based site.

Here is my code:

```
package com.CheckInventory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class CheckInventoryActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    String username; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.124/android");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    }
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()){
            //webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

The site has authentication, but I would like to add some authentication between the app and the site (How do I do this? pass a parameter maybe when the url is invoked), secondly and more importantly, where specifically do I put the onReceivedError so the user never sees the url or the page down if they walk away from the building or loose connection.

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod,String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(Webform.this, "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + description , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I saw this explanation in [Detecting Webview Error and Show Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392318/detecting-webview-error-and-show-message)  but I do not know where to implement it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to create class which extends WebViewClient and implements method **OnReceivedError**

like this

```
class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(Webform.this, "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + description , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

}
```

and then you need to set new WebViewClient to your WebView

```
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: UnQuaiz: I am not sure how to implement your answer,  can you show me the entire code as you would code it?

Comment: I sincerely want to thank you for your time!!! Unfortunately, it did not work.  It still showed the not found and the url.  Ultimately, I am looking for a solution similar to the google play where it shows a retry button if the internet is not available.  Since it is being done by the guys at google, it is possible, I simple wonder how difficult this is.

Comment: Maybe you should check for internet connection first of all, and then show warning and retry button? Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096987/check-real-internet-connection

Comment: UnQuaiz:package com.GlobalChess;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can add `onReceivedError` in Your `HelloWebViewClient` class and handle what you want to handle when you get error.

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
           //Your code to do
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```